# audio call recorder is not working on android 6.0 but working till 5.0?

Tags: android

I have call recording app that work properly till  5.0 for incoming and outgoing calls, but audio recording is not working on android 6.0 please help me to solve this issue. I use media Recorder for this for both Mic, and VOICE_CALL options, butt the result is same?

Answer (score 0):

First, VOICE_CALL is not available to third-party applications.
[android voice_call](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html?hl=es-VE#VOICE_CALL)

Second, Check your runtime permission. Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.
[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)